# How can I make my Docker compose "wait-for-it" script invoke the original container ENTRYPOINT or CMD?

Tags: docker, synchronization, wait, docker-compose

According to [Controlling startup order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/), one can control the order in which [Docker Compose](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-compose) starts containers by using a "[wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it)" script.  Script [`wait-for-it.sh`](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) expects both a `host:port` argument as well as the command that the script should execute when the port is available.  The documentation recommends that Docker Compose invoke this script using the `entrypoint:` option. However, if one uses this option, the container will no longer run its default `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` because `entrypoint:` overrides the default.

How might one provide this default command to `wait-for-it.sh` so that the script can invoke the default `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` when the condition for which it waits is satisfied?

In my case, I've implemented a script `wait-for-file.sh` that polls waiting for a file to exist:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

waitFile="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until test -e $waitFile
do
  >&2 echo "Waiting for file [$waitFile]."
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Found file [$waitFile]."
exec $cmd
```

Docker Compose invokes `wait-for-file.sh` as the entry-point to a slightly custom container derived from [`tomcat:8-jre8`](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/ec75141e3cb6276b07d66c16042152e2d4de119c/8.0/jre8/Dockerfile):

```
  platinum-oms:
    image: opes/platinum-oms
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes_from:
      - liquibase
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - activemq:activemq
    depends_on:
      - liquibase
      - activemq
    entrypoint: /wait-for-file.sh /var/run/liquibase/done
```

Before it exits successfully, another custom container `liquibase` creates `/var/run/liquibase/done` and so `platinum-oms` effectively waits for container `liquibase` to complete.

Once container `liquibase` creates file `/var/run/liquibase/done`, `wait-for-file.sh` prints `Found file [/var/run/liquibase/done].`, but fails to invoke default command [`catalina.sh run`](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/ec75141e3cb6276b07d66c16042152e2d4de119c/8.0/jre8/Dockerfile#L90) in base container `tomcat:8-jre8`.  Why?

#### Test Scenario

I created a simplified test scenario [`docker-compose-wait-for-file`](https://github.com/derekmahar/docker-compose-wait-for-file) to demonstrate my problem.  Container `ubuntu-wait-for-file` waits for container `ubuntu-create-file` to create file `/wait/done` and then I *expect* container `ubuntu-wait-for-file` to invoke the default `ubuntu` container command `/bin/bash`, but instead, it exits.  Why doesn't it work as I expect?

Answer (score 12):

> However, if one uses this option, the container will no longer run its default `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` command because `entrypoint:` overrides the default.

That is expected, which is why the [`wait-for-it`](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) is presented as a *wrapper* script.
It does allow to execute a "subcommand" though:

```
wait-for-it.sh host:port [-s] [-t timeout] [-- command args]
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> The subcommand will be executed regardless if the service is up or not.
> If you wish to execute the subcommand only if the service is up, add the `--strict` argument.

That means the `CMD` part of your image can be used for your actual container command, as its parameters will passed in parameters to the `ENTRYPOINT` command:

```
entrypoint: wait-for-it.sh host:port --
cmd: mycmd myargs
```

This should work... except for [`docker-compose` issue 3140](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3140) (mentioned by the [OP Derek Mahar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107158/derek-mahar) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194733/how-can-i-make-my-docker-compose-wait-for-it-script-invoke-the-original-contai/37195269#comment61930234_37195269))

> ### entrypoint defined in `docker-compose.yml` wipes out `CMD` defined in Dockerfile

That issue [suggests](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3140#issuecomment-767643504) (Jan. 2021)

> If you have a custom image you can add a startscript to the build and call it inside the dockerfile and in the `docker-compose` you can call it again.
> Thats a way to avoid duplicate for more complicated entrypoints.

Comment: From where did you copy the quote about the `--strict` argument?

Comment: Yes, but how could Docker Compose or `wait-for-it` determine and run the original `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` in the container?  Effectively, I want `wait-for-it` to delegate to the default container command after the test succeeds.  How can `wait-for-it` do this if the container hides this command?  At least in my scenario, it's not very useful for `wait-for-it` to wait for a condition before allowing the container to continue if the script cannot run the original container command.

Comment: @DerekMahar It does not: you need an image which has its command only in CMD (that part will be passed automatically to the new entrypoint). The original entrypoint will be overridden. Which not a big deal if its was the defaut `sh -c`.

Comment: VonC, in that case, I think my custom `wait-for-file.sh` script must not be working.  I'll post it in my question and wait for someone to tear it apart.  (No wait-for-it pun intended.)

Comment: (For some reason, StackOverflow prevents me from entering `@VonC` into a comment.)

Comment: To help me troubleshoot this issue, I will run a Docker Compose scenario using `wait-for-file.sh` and two basic containers.

Comment: @DerekMahar a basic container is likely to have a default entrypoint `sh -c`: that can be overridden without problem by `wait-for-file.sh`. The CMD part of that image will be passed as parameter to `wait-for-file.sh`, which is what you want.

Comment: Does https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/045b1c500151a8239fce3cedd1fd656e7c113041/xenial/Dockerfile#L34 qualify?  Project https://github.com/derekmahar/docker-compose-wait-for-file is a test scenario, but container `ubuntu-wait-for-file` doesn't invoke default command `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @DerekMahar 1/ Yes, it does qualifies: no entrypoint means default entrypoint, which can then safely be overridden. 2/ It depends on what `ubuntu-wait-for-file` is. The original script you mention (https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) is supposed to execute the commands passed as parameters to it. Try it with a CMD being `echo test`. Try it with commands wrapped in a `sh -c 'my commands'`. See in both instances if there are passed to and executed by the `wait-for-it.sh script`.

Comment: VonC, but absent any command argument, shouldn't `wait-for-it` (or `wait-for-file`) invoke the default command of the container?

Comment: Yes, it should. Your test dockerfile doesn't seem to have one though.

Comment: VonC, but image `ubuntu`, from which both of my container images derive, has default command https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/045b1c500151a8239fce3cedd1fd656e7c113041/xenial/Dockerfile#L34.  Shouldn't `wait-for-file.sh` invoke this command?

Comment: For your test, it is best to specify your own.

Comment: Okay, but that's not the scenario that I'm trying to represent.  In my "real" case, my container, which has no default command, derives from `tomcat:8-jre8` which has a default command `catalina.sh run`.

Comment: I agree, it should work. I would double-check the documentation around the exact syntax of entrypoint in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: If I append `"echo You called?"` to the `entrypoint` in `docker-compose.yml` it does print "You called?", but absent this command, container `ubuntu-wait-for-file` just exits.

Comment: Docker Compose documentation states that `entrypoint` overrides the default (see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint).  However, I understand that a Dockerfile may effectively have at most one `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` entry.  In the presence of `ENTRYPOINT`, `CMD` serves as arguments to `ENTRYPOINT`.  Absent `ENTRYPOINT`, `CMD` behaves like `ENTRYPOINT` (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).

Comment: So given these results, `wait-for-it` doesn't strike me as a very effective way for Docker Compose to control container startup order, or there is a bug in Docker Compose.

Comment: I'm guessing that under this scenario, derived containers don't correctly inherit the default `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` of the base container.

Comment: @DerekMahar Well spotted. I have included a reference to that issue in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: VonC, are you sure that this is how Docker Compose is supposed to work? Absent bug 3140, would `wait-for-it` even need the extra command parameter? After `wait-for-it` exits (or if it exits), couldn't Docker Compose just delegate directly to the default CMD in the container?

Comment: @DerekMahar Yes, I am sure. CMD is always passed to ENTRYPOINT. wait-for-it will execute the CMD found in the image.

Comment: VonC, I think you're probably right, but until Docker Compose fixes bug 3140, I can't prove it. Nevertheless, it makes sense that Docker Compose `entrypoint` should behave the same as Docker `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: @DerekMahar I agree. I will monitor issue 3140.

Comment: VonC, According to https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3140#issuecomment-234267729, 3140 is actually a bug in the Docker Compose documentation. `wait-for-it` will not execute `CMD` in the image because Docker Engine clobbers the command which may be by design. This is certainly not the behaviour that I expected, though.

Comment: @DerekMahar Yes, https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/3764/files and https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/25012/files confirm this unfortunate design choice.