# Ping until docker is up or until timeout

Tags: docker, ip-address, ping

I am running an app on a docker container,
my app runs on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`
once the app is up - 
(not once the container is running, once the app is ready to use)
i want to run the tests,
If it takes the app more than a minute to run i want to print an error and exit.
**How can i ping to the app until it's up or until the timeout past?**

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: There are a lot of discussions about this topic out of there. In a simple layout, with no service to discover or grouping of containers, I use a simple bash script as a startup box. The script pings the host until the host is up. Next, start up  the application.

Comment: @WasteD, i am using Linux 64-bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my Docker compose "wait-for-it" script invoke the original container ENTRYPOINT or CMD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194733/how-can-i-make-my-docker-compose-wait-for-it-script-invoke-the-original-contai)

Comment: Please take a look at the duplicate I linked above - I know it's for Docker Compose, but you can use the same tool and approach (https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it)

Comment: You can use `netcat`. You can check if a service is online on a specific port for example: `nc -w 5 -z 127.0.0.1 8080`

Comment: Thank's @WasteD, this is the solution!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `netcat`. You can check if a service is online on a specific port for example: `nc -w 5 -z 127.0.0.1 8080`

Added my comment as answer now.